# NodeJS api path

Tags: node.js

I have a project in mind. I want to create an API in NodeJS for communicating with my database. I want to use that API in my Java application as well as in my website. When I use the API I use localhost:3000. How would I make it so the API responds on localhost:3000/projectName/api for example (localhost:3000/projectName would be the website - no idea if this is even the way to do this). I want to sort of prefix with the projectName/api. Is that possible?

Comment: It may be worth showing how your code currently looks

Comment: This `app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.send('Home page')
})` triggers, when I request localhost:3000. I want it to trigger when I request localhost:3000/someting/api if you know what I mean.

Comment: If you simply want to change the route you can just set the path like `app.get('/something/whatever', async (req, res) => {   res.send('Home page') })`

Comment: @Pzdrs: Q: Is your question answered? Please "upvote" and "accept" the reply if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can make all your api routes in an object, namely

```
apis = express.Router()

apis.get("/test", (req, res) => res.status(200))

app.use("/api", apis) // route all /api calls to here

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(500)) // ordering matters, block all / calls
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting the Express [Router](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) module.  Additional links: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes.